# Update database from 2 tables with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

Worked with `phpMyAdmin` and `c#`.

I wanted to update database in the `phpMyAdmin` with `c#`. But, I had an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from bucket inner join color on bucket.color_idcolor = color.idcolor' at line 1

In the `phpMyAdmin`, I had 2 tables in the same database: `bucket` and `color`. In the `bucket` table, I had column: `idbucket`, `volume`, and `color_idcolor`. While in the `color` table, I had column: `idcolor` and `name`.

In `c#`, I made an windows form, where the users can update the database. They can update `volume` (textbox) and `color` (combobox), and press Save button to store the update to the database. This is a few parts of my code:

```
private string idBucket;
private string volume;
private string color;

public void TransferData(string idBucket, string volume, string color)
{
    this.idBucket = idBucket;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.color = color;
}

MySqlConnection conector = new MySqlConnection();

public frmChangeBucket()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    conector.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; database=bucket; uid=root";
}

void ContentCboColor()
{
    conector.Open();

    MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand();
    comand.Connection = conector;
    comand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comand.CommandText = "select idcolor, name from color";

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.SelectCommand = comand;
    da.Fill(dt);
    cboColor.DisplayMember = "name";
    cboColor.ValueMember = "idcolor";
    cboColor.DataSource = dt;

    conector.Close();
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conector.Open();   

    MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand();
    comand.Connection = conector;    
    comand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;  

    int result = 0;

    volume = txtVolume.Text;
    color = cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString();

    comand.CommandText = "update bucket set volume=@volume, color=@color.name, from bucket "
    + "inner join color on bucket.color_idcolor = color.idcolor "
    + "where idBucket=@idbucket";

    komen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idbucket", idBucket);
    komen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@volume", volume);
    komen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color.name", color);
    result += comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comand.Parameters.Clear();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You've changed " + result + " data");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You haven't changed any data");
    }

    conector.Close();   
    this.Close();  
}
```

In `c#`, I just displayed color `name` in combobox. First, users can display a few data from database. I used inner join to display color `name`. To store the update to database, do I have to `inner join` again? Please answer with the right code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead trying to save text in the int field(`color=@color.name`)
you should use:

```
"color_idcolor = color.idcolor"
```

basically:

```
    comand.CommandText = "update bucket set volume=@volume, color_idcolor=@color.idcolor "
        + "where idBucket=@idbucket";
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idbucket", idBucket);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@volume", volume);
    comand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color.idcolor", color);
    result += comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comand.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: It's not error. But, there's mistake. Either I change the data or not, it shows  msgbox: `You haven't changed any data`

Comment: did you edit the differences(komen.Parameters with comand.Parameters)?

Comment: you can do only: conand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: also you can do if(result>0){// you affected more than one row} else if(result==0){//couldn't find the bucket id} else {//different kind of problem}

Comment: I've done that. But, still error with msgbox. Your code can't make the update strored to database

Comment: can you see what the result is? messagebox.show(result.tostring());

Comment: You haven't changed any data

Comment: You've changed 0 data. The result is 0

Comment: can you do the following command and show the results right after you call executenonquery: MessageBox.Show("id: " + idBucket+" volume: "+ volume+" color: "+ color);

Comment: I've done that. And I try to change the volume to 200. The msgbox shows volume: 200. But, the data can't be stored to database

Comment: can you paste the whole message string?

Comment: You haven't changed any data. Id: (I had wrote idBucket here, but it won't show up. I don't know why) volume: 200 color:2

Comment: that is your answer there is no idBucket so it cannot change any row in DB

Comment: where do ypu idBuckt a value?

Comment: I've wrote this: result += comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comand.Parameters.Clear();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You've changed " + result + " data");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You haven't changed any data. Id: " + idBucket + " volume: " + volume + " color: " + color);
                }

Comment: you are not calling this method: public void TransferData(string idBucket, string volume, string color) so there won't be any idBucket value, and of course it won't update any row in MySql

Comment: I had the same code as my post. I changed my code same as your first answer. I didn't change anything, except the if else statement

Comment: can you show me where are you calling this form? and how are you calling?

Comment: Please take a look at the code from my post. I just changed the commandtext part and if else statement

Comment: please can you post the part where you write: frmChangeBucket newForm=new frmChangeBucket();

Comment: I made another winform called Bucket. It has Change Bucket button. This is the code inside it:
`frmChangeBucket formChange = new frmChangeBucket();
formChange.ShowDialog();
formChange.TransferData(idBucket, dateBuy, volume, color, type);`

Comment: you need to change it to this: frmChangeBucket formChange = new frmChangeBucket(); formChange.TransferData(idBucket, dateBuy, volume, color, type); formChange.ShowDialog(); ------ do you understand?

Comment: when you call your new form(frmChangeBucket) you initialize it's every variables with default values(idBucket as empty, color you get that from the combobox and volume from i don't know where) and you try to update the database with no id so there is no row without id. when you change the code and call transfer data before showing the dialog it initializes everything as they need to be :) so please can you accept my answer? if you don't understand just change how it was before and start debugging, then change how it is now and debug again you will understand ;)

Comment: I've accept your answer and upvote it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be;

```
comand.CommandText = "update bucket "
+ "inner join color on bucket.color_idcolor = color.idcolor "
+ "set volume=@volume, color_idcolor=@color.idcolor"    
+ "where idBucket=@idbucket";
```

Remove the `, from bucket` after `color=@color.name` and the `INNER JOIN` should come after `UPDATE` and before `SET`

Comment: Error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from bucket where idBucket=NULL' at line 1`

Comment: Remove `, from bucket` after `color=@color.name`

Comment: Error: `Unknown column 'color' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 0):

One issue is the `from bucket` in your update statement - it needs to be removed. 
Another issue is the join - try to replace the join by a subquery:

```
update bucket 
    set volume=@volume, 
        color_idcolor=@color.idcolor    
where idBucket=@idbucket and 
bucket.color_idcolor in (select color.idcolor from color)
```

Put this into the command text, and it should look like this:

```
comand.CommandText = 
    "update bucket " +
    "set volume=@volume, " +
    "    color_idcolor=@color.idcolor " +   
    "where idBucket=@idbucket " +
    "and bucket.color_idcolor in (select color.idcolor from color)";
```

Then replace

```
komen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color.name", color);
```

by:

```
komen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color.idcolor", colorId);
```

Finally, since you have the color name rather than the color id, the proper color id can be looked up earlier by a separate command `select color.idcolor from color where color.name = @color.name`.

The code for this could be like:

```
string SelectItem(MySqlConnection conn, string Name)
{   
 string result="";  
 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) 
 {
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "select top 1 color.idcolor from color where color.name = @color.name";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color.name", Name);
  result=cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 }
 return result;     
}
```

With this function you can obtain the color Id

```
var colorId = SelectItem(conector, color);
```

**N.B.:** This function assumes that the database connection is already open.

Comment: Error: `Unknown column 'color' in 'field list'`

Comment: because you don't have color field in that table, you have color_idcolor

Comment: @virusivv Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: in the table bucket there is no column:"color" but there is a column:"color_idcolor"

Comment: @virusivv Which color??

Comment: just copy the code that i have provided and compare then you will see. also tell me the result when you change those commands!

Comment: Could you provide the table definitions for the tables `color` and `bucket` please?

Comment: In the bucket table, I had column: idbucket (1; 2; 3), volume (200; 150; 200), and color_idcolor (2; 4; 5). While in the color table, I had column: idcolor (2; 4; 5) and name (Green; Grey; Yellow).

Comment: @Grace Michelle : Thanks, I updated the field name - please try again.

Comment: I've changed the code. Now, it doesn't give me an error. But, it has a same problem with virusivv's solution. So, please look at the comment in virusivv's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 comand.CommandText = "update bucket set volume=@volume, color=@color.name, from bucket "
    + "inner join color on bucket.color_idcolor = color.idcolor "
    + "where idBucket=@idbucket";
```

In update query from keyword will not come and update query you can't use join queries.